# Having trouble with Dynamic Binding in Java

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic, binding, polymorphism

So I have run in to a problem, and have been busting my brain trying to figure out for two days, so I figured it's time to get some help.

So here where my problem is I have an abstract class B extending abstract class A, I am not overriding any methods or anything in B, but specifying more specialized behaviors, variables, and such.

Now here is where my problem comes in, I have a third class lets say class C, the implements all the proper methods, maybe overrides a few (I used the @Override notation so I Know it was done right), and maybe add some of it's own methods, and variables.

Now that's great, but when I try and create an array of type A that I want to use dynamic binding with so I can add objects of type C, or anything else that leads back to A like so.

```
A[] AObjects = new A[3];
Aobject[0] = new C();
so on and so forth
```

now lets say I have a method like getNum(); inside C that only C has, it keeps telling me that getNum(); isn't defined in type A when I try to use it. Am I missing something? Because to my understanding methods are only bound at run time, so I should be able to take a reference variable of type A, and assign it to an object of Type C, and be able to call on all of the public members in C, right? Or are the rules different for arrays?

p.s I used protected for my variables and, public for my methods.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :) thanks

Comment: How are you accessing the object of type C?  `Aobject[0].getNum()` cannot work per Java specification, but `((C) Aobject[0]).getNum()` should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an array of type `A[]` and add an object of type `C` to it, you are effectively upcasting it to `A`. So when you do something like this

```
A[] aObjects = new A[3];
aObjects[0] = new C();
aObjects[0].someMethodOnlyDefinedForC(); // <-- Compile error
```

you can think of the compiler interpreting it like:

```
C objectOfTypeC = new C();
A objectCastToTypeA = (A) objectOfTypeC; // Upcasting to A
A[] aObjects = new A[3];
aObjects[0] = objectCastToTypeA;
objectCastToTypeA.someMethodOnlyDefinedForC(); // <-- Compile error
```

By adding it to the array of `A[]`, you're telling the compiler that only care about the common interface defined in class `A` and not about methods that are defined in any subclasses.

Of course, if you can guarantee that an item at a certain index will always be of type `C`, you could just downcast it back like `((C) aObjects[0]).methodOnlyDefinedForC()` but cheating the type system in that way is a bit of a code smell. Determine if these classes really should be inheriting from each other, or if you can better exploit polymorphism to achieve what you need.

If you truly do need to perform different actions on the items in the array depending on whether they are of type `A`, `B`, or `C`, then you might look into the [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Comment: Thank you! :) greatly apreciate the input! :) and like I said I'm following along with a faiy old game programming book, and I got to a point where theh told me I could do that, and it just wasn't adding up, but yeah makes a lot more sence now! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can only call a method on a class if the class has a definition for that method, so if `A` does not define `getNum()` then you can't call `getNum()` on it.  These are the compiler's rules, not the runtime's rules; `A a` might actually be a `C`, but the compiler has no way of knowing this.  You need to tell the compiler that `a` is a `C` if you want to call `C`'s methods, e.g. `((C)a).getNum();` if it turns out that `a` isn't actually a `C` then you'll get a run-time `ClassCastException`.  To prevent this you can use the `instanceof` operator,

```
if(a instanceof C)
    ((C)a).getNum();
else 
    // do something else
```

but casts like these are often an indication of bad design.  But if you really want to do this, it's a lot faster to use `instanceof` than to catch `ClassCastException`s (about an order of magnitude faster).

Comment: Okay, so what your saying it's not enough to just set a reference variable that was declared as type A equal to an instance of C, I also have to cast it to C to use C's methods? and thank you for the instanceof tip :) I am out right now but will give this a try the second I get back home! And yes, not saying it's well designed, but at the moment I haven't done much game programming, and I am following along with Black art of Java Game Programming, and I hit that wall when they started talking about sprites, and they never talked about it so I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: That's correct, as far as the compiler knows `A c = new C()` is an `A`, not a `C`, at least until you cast it to a `C`.